# Forward Traffic with Window's Host file?

Tags: windows-server-2008, port, hosts, hosts-file

A long time ago I found some guide that showed how to use the Windows Hosts file to forward traffic to another IP/Port. We setup a clients server on one IP/Port, and they wanted it changed to another IP/Port on the same machine, but are now asking that we forward UDP/TCP traffic to it as well.

I am pretty sure this is doable but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it now after Google searching for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably remembering incorrectly. The only thing that `/etc/hosts` controls is local DNS lookups -- you can't use it to swap ports around or forward data sent from other machines.

You may be able to forward connections using a firewall package or router.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. The original IP/Port and new IP/Port are on the same machine. I just need to forward incoming traffic from the original to the new one.

Comment: Still not happening without something other than `/etc/hosts`.